# How can i use the http.get for delphi xe2 ios firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Component or a code to use it for getting a source code of the page in a memo.
Thank you

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439974/what-networking-components-are-available-for-firemonkey-ios-apps) should help. See the accepted answer.

Comment: uses idhttp and then var http:idhhtp http.create http.get(url) http.destroy but when compile in firemonkey says that cant create that form and shows me command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1.. Some other way please to succed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//It works on Win32/Win64/OS X !

procedure TMainForm.Button_DownloadClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  URL      = 'http://web.t-online.hu/karpo/downloads/3dc32480.zip';

var
  fsSource: TFileStream;
  FILENAME_Local: String;

begin
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
     FILENAME_Local:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'proba.zip';
  {$ENDIF}

  {$IFDEF MACOS}             //OS X user !
     FILENAME_Local:='/users/zoltankarpati/public/proba.zip';
  {$ENDIF}

  if FileExists(FILENAME_Local) then
  begin
    fsSource := TFileStream.Create(FILENAME_Local, fmOpenWrite);
  end
  else
  begin
    fsSource := TFileStream.Create(FILENAME_Local, fmCreate);
  end;

  try
    IdHTTP.Get(URL, fsSource);
  finally
    fsSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```